# How do I get current color and display the name to an EditText

Tags: android, colors, android-custom-view

My app prints chars to a custom view and I can set the color of printed chars with the following:

```
public void setColor(){

    curColor++;
    int NUMBEROFCOLORS = 5;
    curColor = curColor % (NUMBEROFCOLORS -1);
    switch(curColor){
        case 0:
            paintTxt.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            break;
        case 1:
            paintTxt.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            break;
        case 2:
            paintTxt.setColor(Color.RED);
            break;
        case 3:
            paintTxt.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            break;
        case 4:
            paintTxt.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            break;
        case 5:
            paintTxt.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            break;

    }


}
```

And then use it on the onClick method of a button:

```
colorChanger.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myCustomView.setColor(); //this changes the color of chars that are being printed to the custom view
       //  myEditText.setText(myCustomView.getColor()); // This doesnt do anything
                }
            }
    );
}
```

The bellow works fine, however I would also print the current color in an EditText. Say when White is set, print something like "Current color: White" and so forth.
I can use something like:

```
myEditText.setText(myCustomView.getColor());
```

It doesnt work. I'm aware I'm not doing things as they should be done, still a beginner.

creating a getter the calling the code above, crashes the app :

```
public int getColor() {
    return curColor;
}
```

The log :

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.esqmo.apps.digitalraineffects, PID: 11373
>       android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1

Please advice me understand how I can achieve this.

Comment: What is `myCustomView` here ? Does it have a valid implementation for `getColor()`?

Comment: I just edited with getColor which I doubt is a good implementation. myCustomView is the custom view on which averything is printed

Comment: So did your problem solved ?

Comment: Not yet. It only prints number instead of color name

Comment: please post your latest code

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it looked like `setText` is `String`, but `getColor` return `int`.

So you have to change your code to

```
myEditText.setText(myCustomView.getColor()+"");
```

or to this

```
myEditText.setText(Integer.toString(myCustomView.getColor()));
```

To prints color name instead of `int` in `editText`

```
String colorName = color(myCustomView.getColor());
myEditText.setText(colorName);


public String color(int colorNum)
{
     String color;
     switch(colorNum) {
        case 0:
            color = Color.GREEN;
            ......
            break;
        case 1:
             .....
            break;
    }
    return color;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the rapid answer. This works, except it only prints int instead of color name (exemple 1, 2, 3 etc). What should I do to get the name?

Comment: you can create another `switch-case` method like how you do for the `setColor()`. If is 1 , return blue and so on.

Comment: Thanks will try that way